# Getting Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded after upgrade to Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2

I have just gone upgraded my Ionic 2 app to Ionic 3, all of framework, Ionic native, and the CLI.

I now have the following setup..

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^4.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "^4.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^3.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^3.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^3.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.8.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "c3": "^0.4.11",
        "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "js-logger": "^1.3.0",
        "jslogger": "^1.0.3",
        "jszip": "^3.1.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.17.1",
        "moment-duration-format": "^1.3.0",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "semaphore-async-await": "^1.3.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.10"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.0.0",
        "@types/c3": "^0.4.38",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.42",
        "@types/jszip": "0.0.32",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.51",
        "@types/moment-duration-format": "^1.3.1",
        "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
        "codecov": "^1.0.1",
        "install": "^0.8.7",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
        "karma": "^1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
        "ts-node": "^2.1.0",
        "tslint": "^4.4.2",
        "tslint-eslint-rules": "^3.3.0",
        "typescript": "^2.2.1"
      },
```

Now, if I build with the -prod flag (it id fine without this), I get the following error...

```
    [16:50:08]  webpack started ...
    Error: ./~/jszip/lib/index.js
    Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at Object.forEachChild (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:14735:26)
        at traverse (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:7271:31)
        at Object.forEachReturnStatement (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:7251:16)
        at checkAndAggregateReturnExpressionTypes (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40055:16)
        at getReturnTypeFromBody (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39965:29)
        at getReturnTypeOfSignature (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31190:28)
        at resolveNewExpression (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39483:21)
        at resolveSignature (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39639:28)
        at getResolvedSignature (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39669:26)
        at checkCallExpression (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39696:29)
     @ ./src/providers/file-logger.ts 58:0-28
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/app/main.ts,./~/d3/d3.js
    Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
        at String.replace (native)
        at formatStringFromArgs (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:2365:21)
        at Object.chainDiagnosticMessages (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:2433:20)
        at reportNonexistentProperty (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38290:28)
        at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38332:
    21)
        at checkPropertyAccessExpression (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38274:20)
        at checkExpressionWorker (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41158:28)
        at checkExpression (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41115:42)
        at checkExpressionWithContextualType (D:\dev\myapp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40983:26)
     @ ./src/pages/mypage/mypage.ts 61:0-25
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/app/main.ts
```

I have tracked this down to the 2 libs  [C3/D3](http://c3js.org/), and [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). If I use either of these in a **small newly created** Ionic 3 app, then there is **not** a problem.

I have gone through many many other reports of webpack throwing this error, but just cannot see why this is now happening for me, in my existing project.

This occurs for either the new Ionic CLI version 3, or for an older version (2.2.3) when I downgraded to it.

**[UPDATE1]**

Running on a second machine (Windows 10) with node v6.9.4 (the above was node 7.something), and npm 4.2.0, I get similar but differently formatted error...

```
    [16:31:04]  webpack started ...
    [16:31:35]  webpack finished in 31.23 s
    [16:31:35]  sass started ...
    [16:31:36]  transpile bundle started ...
    [16:31:44]  build prod failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    [16:31:44]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
    [16:31:44]  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at checkNonNullExpression (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38258:40)
        at resolveNewExpression (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39433:34)
        at resolveSignature (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39639:28)
        at getResolvedSignature (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39669:26)
        at checkCallExpression (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:39696:29)
        at checkExpressionWorker (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41163:28)
        at checkExpression (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41115:42)
        at checkExpressionCached (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40996:38)
        at H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40058:32
        at traverse (H:\dev\myapp\upgradeto3\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:7255:28)
```

**[UPDATE2]**

As another test, I added a new empty page, and added nothing but the C3 import, and then a call to a single function (generate) from the library.

This new page gets the same error.

Does anyone have any idea of how to track this down / fix this problem? I am out of ideas, and I just can't restart the project from blank again.

Thanks in advance for any help

**[UPDATE3]**

I thought I'd try to update TypeScript to the latest 2.3.2. When I rerun npm install, I do get some warnings..

```
    +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.1.0
    +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@4.1.0
    `-- typescript@2.3.2

    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (curre
    nt: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN ng2-translate@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
    npm WARN ng2-translate@5.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

I don't quite understand the two `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` as I do have exactly `@angular/core@4.1.0` and `@angular/http@4.1.0` installed.

At any rate, I still get the same overflow. Really not sure what to try next. Once again, these libraries both build fine in a newly created Ionic application, maybe because it is a lot smaller?

Also I did find [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12735), but it looks a little different to mine here...

Comment: Which version of node you are using? Its working fine with node v6.10.3 and npm v3.10.10

Comment: On the machine I initially tried this on I was running node version 7.something. I've tried the build on a second machine, and this one has node v6.9.4, npm 4.2.0. I get the same error, though with not as much details as where it is coming from, I will add these to the question (as can't format here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution has been to have the latest Ionic, including the latest CLI, **except** holding TypeScript at **2.3.0** as suggested by imgx64 [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/996)

Answer (score 0):

Similar error when running `ionic cordova build browser --prod` after uptdate from Ionic 3.2.1 to 3.3.0. It only happens when I use `--prod` parameter.

Error log:

```
$ ionic cordova build browser --prod
Running app-scripts build: --prod --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

    [13:22:25]  build prod started ...
    [13:22:25]  clean started ...
    [13:22:25]  clean finished in 16 ms
    [13:22:25]  copy started ...
    [13:22:25]  ngc started ...
    [13:22:37]  ngc finished in 11.64 s
    [13:22:37]  preprocess started ...
    [13:22:37]  deeplinks started ...
    [13:22:37]  deeplinks finished in 594 ms
    [13:22:37]  optimization started ...
    [13:22:38]  copy finished in 12.65 s
    [13:22:57]  optimization finished in 19.56 s
    [13:22:57]  preprocess finished in 20.15 s
    [13:22:57]  webpack started ...
    [WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
    Error: ./~/d3/d3.js
    Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at checkNonNullExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38397:40)
        at checkPropertyAccessExpressionOrQualifiedName (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38455:24)
        at checkPropertyAccessExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38413:20)
        at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41300:28)
        at checkExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41257:42)
        at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40834:28)
        at checkBinaryExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40827:20)
        at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41335:28)
        at checkExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41257:42)
        at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Projetos\MyProject\Frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40834:28)
     @ ./~/c3/c3.js 830:70-83
     @ ./src/components/c3-chart-component/c3-chart-adapter.ts
     @ ./src/components/c3-chart-component/c3-chart-component.ts
     @ ./src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src async
     @ ./~/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
     @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
     @ ./src/app/main.ts
```

Comment: We have a build script issue added for this [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/996). In my case it seems to be the minification that is causing it.